# How to analyze runtime performance from a tampermonkey userscript?

Tags: javascript, performance, debugging

I've been trying to debug/profile a JS script first on Tampermonkey with Google Devtools and then on Greasemonkey with Firebug (now included by default in Firefox).

I know that the easy answer is to use console.log or alerts but this doesn't let me debug step by step and navigate the code. Also, I cannot analyze runtime performance if the browser doesn't recognize my injected script which is the case.

Comment: you can use `debugger` keyword in your code

Comment: I can indeed. But even with that I am not able to analyze performance.